# I do not know why this is happening. jedis Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory'

Tags: spring-boot, redis, jedis

An error has been detected after running the application.
I can not find any problems and I need help.

The package structure consists of config and controller.

spring-boot-starter-data-redis
redis.clients jedis 3.0.1

```
package com.arthur.springbootredis.config;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericToStringSerializer;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {

        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = null;

        try {
            RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(0);
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setHostName("localhost");
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPort(6379);

            jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);

            jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxTotal(50);
            jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxIdle(50);
        } catch (RedisConnectionFailureException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        template.setValueSerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<Object>(Object.class));
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        return template;
    }
}
```

---

Below is the error content

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jedisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/arthur/springbootredis/config/RedisConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jedisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/util/SafeEncoder

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I've found a problem. Why is the jedis version a problem? I do not know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use Jedis 3.0.x which makes breaking changes to the API that was provided by Jedis 2.x. The exception is being thrown by `JedisConnectionFactory` which is part of Spring Data Redis and, at the time of writing, Spring Data Redis only supports Jedis 2.x. Support for Jedis 3 [has been implemented](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-749) but not yet released. If you want to use Spring Data Redis, you should stick to Jedis 2.x for the time being. Support for Jedis 3.0 will be released in Spring Data Redis 2.2 which is part of the Spring Data Moore release train and will be included in Spring Boot 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Since July 2019, Spring Boot 2.X was compatible with Jedis 3.X (See [Upgrade to Jedis 3.1.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17622) for more info).
For those who use Gradle, here is my combination:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'redis.clients:jedis:3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the compatibility of different dependency versions.

Try setting your maven `jedis` dependency to

```
<dependency>
<groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
<artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
<version>3.10.0</version>
<type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

and

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```